# How can I get a list of users that are assigned to a security role in .net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have already seen the method:

```
GetRolesForUser
```

But is there a way using the membership providers that I can see the users in a role? I searched around and still didn't find a simple way to create a report list of users for a given role.

Comment: What security store are you using as your back end? Built in SQL membership provider, active directory, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [`GetUsersInRole`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.getusersinrole.aspx) method:

> The GetUsersInRole method calls the GetUsersInRole method of the default role provider to retrieve the user names associated with a role from the data source.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using the membership providers, as you have no idea where the group membership comes from. It could be from AD, from a database, from an external provider (using e.g. WIF), etc. If you want to look up users in a group, you can probably do this against AD using LDAP, but you can't use the membership providers for this. It has no way of knowing this.